# Rewriting a text file after reading it

Tags: c#, text, text-files

i got a file that is store in my appliction directory, and he got some site list.
i dont have any problem reading it, but when i want to write to it, i get

```
System.ArgumentException: Stream is not writeable
```

this is how i accsess the file:

```
  FileStream theTextFileStream = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/fourmlinks.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

and this is the function that throw me the expection:

```
public static void WriteNewTextToFile(string text, FileStream theFile)
    {
        string fileText = GetAllTextFromFile(theFile);
        ArrayList fileLIst = populateListFromText(fileText);

        using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(theFile))
        {
            fileWriter.Write(String.Empty);
            for (int i = 0; i < fileLIst.Count; i++)
            {
                fileWriter.WriteLine(fileLIst[i].ToString());        
            }
        }
    }
```

the function read the old and new text and add it to an arry. then i clean the file from every thing, and rewriting it with the old and new data from the arry i made.

i dont know if that will help but here is the file proprites:

```
Build Action: None
Copy To Out Put Directory: Copy always
```

why i cant rewrite the file?

this is the function i use to read the file content:

```
public static string GetAllTextFromFile(FileStream theFile)
    {
        string fileText = "";

        using (theFile)
        {
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(theFile))
            {
                string currentLine = "";
                while ((currentLine = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    fileText += currentLine + "\n";
                }

            }
        }

        return fileText;

    }
```

Comment: Are you using the same `FileStream` that you used to open the file?

Comment: How do you *read* from the file?

Comment: i added the function that i use to read the file.

Comment: Are you certified that your file name is correct?! "fourmlinks"

Comment: I find it interesting that you've disposed of the stream after reading it, yet you're not getting a `ObjectDisposedException` when you attempt to write to it. I would think that would be raised before your `ArgumentException`

Comment: @FelipeKM yes im sure, i open it and read is content when i open the app and i can see all the content.

Comment: make sure your file is not opened in some other application - notepad or similar

Comment: BTW, don't trust `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will give you, at any time, the path to the directory you expect. Use this method instead: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))`. Taken from this other [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253468/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-directory-from-which-an-assembly-is-executing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Read/Write file access as `third` parameter -

```
FileStream theTextFileStream = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/fourmlinks.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite
);
```

Important - Remove `using(theFile)` statement:

```
public static string GetAllTextFromFile(FileStream theFile)
{
        string fileText = "";

        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(theFile))
        {
            string currentLine = "";
            while ((currentLine = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                fileText += currentLine + "\n";
            }

        }


    return fileText;

}
```

Do not use `using` construct in your case as it will close the underlying stream as in your case you have to manually `open` and `close` `stream` objects.

This will allow you to write in the file as well.

For more information refer following links -

- [FileStream Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft.aspx)
- [FileAccess Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f.aspx)

Comment: still not working, im getting the same exeption. i open the file in a Form i made on runtime, can that effect the stream?

Comment: i added the file with visual studio, how can i use visual studio to see if he is read only?

Comment: Remove `using (theFile)` from `GetAllTextFromFile` method

Comment: `using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(theFile))` also closes the underlying file stream object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close.aspx

Comment: yes the problem was that i needed to make sure the stream is still alive, i change some stuff and i just reopen it every time i needed to do somthing. thx